# flipView and Page indicator UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am facing a problem in synchronising the FlipView with the Page Indicator,this is my code:

```
 <Grid>
        <FlipView x:Name="flipView1">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        </FlipView>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=flipView1}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectCommand, ElementName=grid, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <Grid Height="30" Width="30" Margin="10,10">
                            <Ellipse Fill="#2c3389" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"  >
                                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                    <CompositeTransform ScaleX="1.25" ScaleY="1.25"/>
                                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            </Ellipse>
                            <Ellipse Fill="Gray" Stroke="#2c3389"  />
                        </Grid>
```

and this is how I get the ItemSource to the FlipView in the code behind:

```
var tests = new List<SampleItem>()
{
    test1,
    test2
};
            flipView1.ItemsSource = tests;
        }
```

I can move from one page to another with my flipView,but the page indicator doesn't work :/
any help please,how can I bound Both the FlipView and the ItemsControl to same collection

thanks for help

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear. You should bind list to the ItemsSource, but what is "dataBinding link"? What do you mean? Why you didn't use ListView, like in sample from the link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should bind the selectedIndex of your ItemsControl :

```
<ItemsControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=flipView1}"
 ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=flipView1}" >

</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: What if my Flipview is set Statically in the Xaml? When I try your method it crashes throwing an unhandled exception. This is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423498/set-itemssource-of-control-to-another-controls-itemssource-that-is-static-and-s/37434916#37434916

Answer (score 3):

for UWP there is no SelectedIndex event in ItemsControl so I used Gridview instead

```
 <GridView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=companiesFlipView}" 
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=companiesFlipView}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                      IsItemClickEnabled="False"
                      IsEnabled="False"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10">
                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="10" Height="10">
                                <Ellipse Fill="Black"></Ellipse>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </GridView>
```

we can improve the styles for selected item :)

Answer (score 0):

Aditional style indicator

```
<Style x:Key="LegendItemContainerStyle" TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,4,4" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMinHeight}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <!--We add the actual control in the container because we need the selection state to change
                        the control's color.-->
                        <Ellipse Width="5" Height="5"
                                 Fill="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                            Converter={StaticResource SelectedLegendItemToColorConverter}}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

FlipView

```
<FlipView Visibility="Visible" x:Name="flipView" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedInstructionItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
              Background="#FF494949" ItemsSource="{Binding InstructionItems}">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource FirstRowHeight}" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource SecondRowHeight}" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
                            <TransitionCollection>
                                <EdgeUIThemeTransition Edge="Left" />
                            </TransitionCollection>
                        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderText}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource TextHeaderStyle}" />

                        <Image Stretch="Uniform" MaxWidth="335" Grid.Row="1"
                               Source="{Binding Image}" Margin="36,0"
                               Visibility="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}" />

                        <Button Content="Get Started" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Visibility="{Binding TargetPage, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,32"
                                Style="{StaticResource ColoredButtonStyle}"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateToTargetPageCommand,
                                    ElementName=pageRoot}"
                                Click="Button_Click"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </Grid>

                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="/Assets/Welcome/gradient-white.png"
                           Height="26" MaxWidth="500" Stretch="Fill"
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,-10" />

                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="{StaticResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}">
                        <Grid Style="{StaticResource TextGridStyle}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
                                    <TransitionCollection>
                                        <EdgeUIThemeTransition Edge="Bottom" />
                                    </TransitionCollection>
                                </StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
                                <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource TextContentStyle}"
                                           Text="{Binding ContentText}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource FirstRowHeight}" />
            <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource SecondRowHeight}" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <GridView Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedInstructionItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding InstructionItems}"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LegendItemContainerStyle}" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Converter

```
public class SelectedLegendItemToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var isSelected = (bool) value;
        return isSelected
            ? Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush"] as Brush
            : Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlForegroundListMediumBrush"] as Brush;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```