# Set ItemsSource of Control to another control's ItemsSource that is Static and set in Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, itemssource, flipview

I am building a UWP Windows 10 App. In a Page I have a FlipView that has static items. Instead of binding them to an ItemsSource, it was easier to set them in Xaml as:

```
<FlipView x:Name="myFlipView">
<FlipViewItem>...</FlipViewItem>
<FlipViewItem>...</FlipViewItem>
</FlipView>
```

I want to add an Indicators Control to this FlipView as in this tutorial: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/04/lets-code-build-your-own-flipview-page.html

When I want to set the ItemsSource of my `<ItemsControl x:Name="Indicators">`I want to set it to the FlipView's ItemsSource. 
I tried setting it in code as `Indicators.ItemsSource = myFlipView.ItemsSource;` but it is empty as it is set statically in Xaml. Any idea how to do that?

---

**Edit:**

I have used a GridView instead of an ItemsControl since ItemsControl doesn't have a SelectedIndex property like mentioned here: [flipView and Page indicator UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154123/flipview-and-page-indicator-uwp)

I set it like that:

`<GridView x:Name="Indicators" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=myFlipView}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=myFlipView}">...</GridView>`

But it is crashing and throws an Unhandled Exception that I can't catch.